# console.log printing statements in the wrong order for learnyounode node.js tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm making a `GET` request, storing the data, and then noting the response is over.  I have one `console.log` statement for when I'm done receiving the data and another for when the program has finished.  See below:

```
var a = 1
var b = 10e9

http.get(process.argv[2], function(response){
  response.pipe(bl())
  response.on('end', function(){
    console.log("Finished receiving data")
  })
})

while(a != b){
  a++
}

console.log("Program has finished")
```

In this case, I would expect the order of the print statements to be

```
Finished receiving data
Program has finished
```

because I would expect the end of the response to occur before the `while` loop terminates.  However, regardless of whether that loop is 1 to 2 or 1 to 100000000000, I always get

```
Program has finished
Finished receiving data
```

Why are the print statements happening in this order?

Comment: It's an async call - the rest of the code runs while that call takes time to process.

Comment: I understand the `http.get()` call is asynchronous, but right after it is a huge loop.  The asynchronous call should finish before that loop finishes.

Comment: Such a loop will “block” everything else that JS does. Even if on an underlying level the HTTP reuqest itself might be finished before your loop is – everything else that _handles_ that request in your script will (be forced to) wait until your loop is finished.

Comment: @CBroe, that makes sense, thanks.  Still, I'd like to make multiple asynchonous calls and wait for them all to complete before executing another set of code.  If this doesn't work, what's the correct `node.js` way of doing it?

Comment: Also, feel free to submit what you've already posted as an answer.

Comment: Which lesson from `learnyounode` are you talking about?

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros, `juggling_async` but it doesn't matter as I found a way to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all of the fuss about its asynchronous expressivity, node.js is single threaded and will only have one thread of execution per process - that means only one line of code will be executed at a time.

When you make the asynchronous call to `http.get`, node.js sends off an HTTP GET and defers execution of the callback until (1) the callback is ready to be called and (2) it runs out of synchronous (blocking) code to run. This explains why you always see `"Program is finished"` first - node.js has finished executing its blocking code and is ready to move on to handling the asynchronous callback that contains `"Finished receiving data"`.