# Typical JavaScript asynchronous issue

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I beleive this issue should be fairly easily summed up, the following code produces the following output.
The code:

```
var checker = 0;
var increment = 0;
examboardData.forEach(function (examSeed) {
    examBoard.create(examSeed, function (err, exam) {
        console.log("Creating new examboard");
        if (err) {
            console.log("Could not create new examboard\n" + err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Created examboard");
            increment = 0;
            for (var i = 12 * checker; i < questionData.length - 24 + (12 * checker); i++) {
                console.log("Atleast do this in order");
                question.create(questionData[i], function (err, question) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Could not create new question\n" + err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Created question");
                        for (var t = math.floor(increment / 4); t < exam.modules.length; t++) {
                            for (var u = 0; u < exam.modules[t].topics.length; u++) {
                                exam.modules[t].topics[u].questions.push(question);
                            }
                        }
                        exam.save();
                    }
                });
                increment++;
            }
            checker++;
        }
    });
});
```

The output:

```
Creating new examboard
Created examboard
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Creating new examboard
Created examboard
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Creating new examboard
Created examboard
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Atleast do this in order
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
Created question
```

The evident issue being it only prints `Created question` at the end instead of in order, if anyone can provide an answer as to how to fix this or merely point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.
Here is the full context of the top code (https://hastebin.com/dafugudaya.lua) lines 204-277.

Comment: Don't rely on `console` statements to be output in the same order they are written.

Comment: @chazsolo I would presume the order in which the 'console' statements run is also the order in which the surrounding code runs (Although admittedly I could be rather wrong).

Comment: You should read about how asynchronous work. There is no issue here, just javascript design. Some similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25320512/6320039. I don't have time enough now but I'm sure your question has already an answer here

Comment: JonathanWoollett-light You're right. I think what @chazsolo actually meant is that you shouldn't rely on asynchronous callbacks to be executed in the same order as they are found in the code.

Comment: @Bergi yes, perhaps I could have explained a bit more. Thanks. However, there are still differences to be aware of even without asynchronous code due to differences in browser implementation. My [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426397/order-of-execution-for-console-statements-for-different-browsers) was for this exact issue.

Comment: @chazsolo No, that question has nothing to do with asynchronous code. Sure, the logs might be buffered before actually appearing in the console (especially with long-running synchronous code), but they're not reordered.

Comment: @Bergi Fully agree with you - just trying to point out the inconsistencies.